# find img attribute and change src value inside divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a structure like:

```
<div id="so1" class="card over"  data-direction="right" gal="gal1" >        
      <div class="front" >
    <img src="img1.jpg" width ="100%;" height ="100%;" alt="">
      </div>         
      <div class="back" style="background-color:#99ca3c;">
      </div>         
</div>
```

to recognize this sections I do

```
change_it = function (id,effect, img ) {
   $('#' + id).toggleClass(effect);
   $('#' + id).attr('img', img);
}
```

I call it

```
change_it ("so1", "flipping-right" ,"imgs/img1/2.jpg");
```

However it is not changing its value, How can I access this img attribute, if I only have id of parent div? 
I mean, the structure is `div->div->img`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the *image* and change its *src* attribute:

```
change_it = function (id,effect, img ) {
   $('#' + id).toggleClass(effect);
   $('#' + id).find('img').attr('src', img);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `so1` is div id but you are using

```
$('#' + id).find('img').attr('src', img);
```

for a div.

Here you need to find the image tag first existed in that div.Then change the src of that image.

Comment: You want the `src` attribute... there is no `img` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign img to div you can set its background image.

```
$('#' + id).css('background-img', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')'
```

Comment: `div`s don't have `src` attribute, `img`s do.